# how to improve neural network prediction, classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am trying to learn some neural networks for fun. I decided to try to classify some pokemon legendary cards, from a data set from kaggle. I read up on documentations and followed machine learning mastery guides, while reading up on medium to try to understand the process.

My problem/ question  : i tried predicting and everything is predicting "0". i assume that is false. is my 92% false accuracy? i read something about false accuracy online.

please help!

Some background information : the dataset has 800 rows, 12 columns. i am predicting the last column ( true/false). I am using attributes of the data that has numerical and categorical. i label encoded the numerical categories. 92% of these cards are False. 8% are true.

i sampled and ran a neural network on 200 cards, and got 91% accuracy... i also reset everything and got a 92% accuracy on all 800 cards. am i overfitting?

thank you for help in advance

```
dataFrame = dataFrame.fillna(value='NaN')

labelencoder = LabelEncoder()

numpy_dataframe = dataFrame.as_matrix()
numpy_dataframe[:, 0] = labelencoder.fit_transform(numpy_dataframe[:, 0])
numpy_dataframe[:, 1] = labelencoder.fit_transform(numpy_dataframe[:, 1])

numpy_dataframe
X = numpy_dataframe[:,0:10]
Y = numpy_dataframe[:,10]
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=10)
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))

#this shows that we have 91.88% accuracy with the whole dataframe


dataFrame200False = dataFrame 
dataFrame200False['Legendary'] = dataFrame200False['Legendary'].astype(str)
dataFrame200False= dataFrame200False[dataFrame200False['Legendary'].str.contains("False")]

dataFrame65True = dataFrame

dataFrame65True['Legendary'] = dataFrame65True['Legendary'].astype(str)
dataFrame65True= dataFrame65True[dataFrame65True['Legendary'].str.contains("True")]

DataFrameFalseSample = dataFrame200False.sample(200)
DataFrameFalseSample

dataFrameSampledTrueFalse = dataFrame65True.append(DataFrameFalseSample, ignore_index=True)
dataFrameSampledTrueFalse

#label encoding the files
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()

numpy_dataSample = dataFrameSampledTrueFalse.as_matrix()
numpy_dataSample[:, 0] = labelencoder.fit_transform(numpy_dataSample[:, 0])
numpy_dataSample[:, 1] = labelencoder.fit_transform(numpy_dataSample[:, 1])

numpy_dataSample
a = numpy_dataframe[:,0:10]
b = numpy_dataframe[:,10]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(a, b, epochs=1000, batch_size=10)

scoresSample = model.evaluate(a, b)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scoresSample[1]*100))

dataFramePredictSample = dataFrame.sample(500)
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()

numpy_dataframeSamples = dataFramePredictSample.as_matrix()
numpy_dataframeSamples[:, 0] = labelencoder.fit_transform(numpy_dataframeSamples[:, 0])
numpy_dataframeSamples[:, 1] = labelencoder.fit_transform(numpy_dataframeSamples[:, 1])

Xnew = numpy_dataframeSamples[:,0:10]
Ynew = numpy_dataframeSamples[:,10]


# make a prediction
Y = model.predict_classes(Xnew)
# show the inputs and predicted outputs
for i in range(len(Xnew)):
    print("X=%s, Predicted=%s" % (Xnew[i], Y[i]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem:

The problem is that, as you stated, your dataset is heavily **imbalanced**. This means that you have a lot more training examples for class 0 than class 1. This causes the network, during training, to develop a heavy bias towards predicting class 0.

#### Evaluation:

The first thing you should do is **not** use accuracy as your evaluation measure! My suggestion would be to draw a **confusion matrix** so that you see exactly what the model is predicting. You could also look into macro-averaging (read [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/36302/34269) if you're not familiar with the technique).

#### Dealing with the problem:

There are two ways you can improve the performance of the model:

- **Resample** your data, so that it becomes **balanced**. You have a couple of options here. The most common way is to **oversample** (e.g. [SMOTE](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html)) the minority class so that it reaches the population of the majority. Another option is to **undersample** (e.g. [Clustering Centroids](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.under_sampling.ClusterCentroids.html#imblearn.under_sampling.ClusterCentroids)) the majority class so that it's population drops to that of the minority.
- Use **class weights** during training. This forces the network to **pay more attention** to samples from the minority class (read [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/37352/34269) for more info).

Comment: thank you for your answer / suggestion. ignoring that my data set is imbalanced. based on what i have so far, what do you think of my approach? i know for sure that i will avoid imbalanced datasets in the future. 

i read up about confusions matrix and i will definitely take your suggestion. what do you think of relative square error and error calculations though? do you think i should consider them as well?

Comment: Metrics regarding error have more to do with your model **internally**. They are meant to compare the **probability** your model outputs (not the actual prediction) with the target value. This is used for training the model, but it isn't much when evaluating it. Most commonly you are interested in your model making **correct predictions** not highly confident ones. If you are looking at a single metric that evaluates the model's performance I'd chose something like the F1 measure, the Geometric Mean score or the Area under the ROC.